# Why is creating a class in Python so much slower than instantiating a class?

Tags: python, performance, class, memory-management

I found that creation of a class is way slower than instantiation of a class.

```
>>> from timeit import Timer as T
>>> def calc(n):
...     return T("class Haha(object): pass").timeit(n)

<<After several these 'calc' things, at least one of them have a big number, eg. 100000>>

>>> calc(9000)
15.947055101394653
>>> calc(9000)
17.39099097251892
>>> calc(9000)
18.824054956436157
>>> calc(9000)
20.33335590362549
```

Yeah, create 9000 classes took 16 secs, and becomes even slower in the subsequent calls.

And this:

```
>>> T("type('Haha', b, d)", "b = (object, ); d = {}").timeit(9000)
```

gives similar results.

But instantiation don't suffer:

```
>>> T("Haha()", "class Haha(object): pass").timeit(5000000)
0.8786070346832275
```

5000000 instances in less than one sec.

What makes the creation this expensive?

And why the creation process become slower?

**EDIT:**

How to reproduce:

start a fresh python process, the initial several "calc(10000)"s give a number of 0.5 on my machine. And try some bigger values, calc(100000), it can't end in even 10secs, interrupt it, and calc(10000), gives a 15sec.

**EDIT:**

Additional fact:

If you gc.collect() after 'calc' becomes slow, you can get the 'normal' speed at beginning, but the timing will increasing in subsequent calls

```
>>> from a import calc
>>> calc(10000)
0.4673938751220703
>>> calc(10000)
0.4300072193145752
>>> calc(10000)
0.4270968437194824
>>> calc(10000)
0.42754602432250977
>>> calc(10000)
0.4344758987426758
>>> calc(100000)
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "a.py", line 3, in calc
    return T("class Haha(object): pass").timeit(n)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/timeit.py", line 194, in timeit
    timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
  File "<timeit-src>", line 6, in inner
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> import gc
>>> gc.collect()
234204
>>> calc(10000)
0.4237039089202881
>>> calc(10000)
1.5998330116271973
>>> calc(10000)
4.136359930038452
>>> calc(10000)
6.625348806381226
```

Comment: Why does this matter? In any case, your timings are affected by the load on your system at the time. They are really only useful for comparisons performed at pretty much the same time. I get about 0.5s for 9000 class creations.

Comment: @Marcin: there's a 1000x difference.. why are you nit-picking about those small details?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath What small details? These results cannot be replicated elsewhere.

Comment: @Marcin: huh? of course you cannot replicate the exact values ... but the magnitudes should be the same (the argument of timeit is the key thing here!).

Comment: I'm more curious about the slowing down than I am the initial speed. That's a pretty interesting (to me) little edge case.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Not even the magnitudes should remain the same - timeit is only for relative tests. The point is that testing elsewhere (such as on ideone) shows that class creation is not very expensive. This is a non-issue.

Comment: @KirkStrauser See my ideone test. No slowdown is shown.

Comment: @Marcin you have just proven that OP has a slower computer than ideone. Go try with 5000000 class creations and compare it with 5000000 instance creations and tell us it's equally fast. The distance will obviously change, the point was that T(creation) > T(instantiation)

Comment: @soulcheck No, this question identifies class creation as very slow, and slower as more tests are executed. Actual testing shows that it is not very slow and does not get slower. What I have shown is that OPs results are spurious.

Comment: @Marcin: http://ideone.com/UBvRf

Comment: @Marcin `very slow` is a relative term and obviously dependent on the machine parameters and personal taste. java was `very slow` on machines used 15 years ago and now you have minecraft ;)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath What's your point? That does not show creation as being remotely as slow as OP's tests, and for obvious reasons, it says nothing about the existence of a trend. Why are you desperate to defend results that no-one can replicate?

Comment: @Marcin I could replicated it on my pc, and while it's not an ever-increasing trend, it gets around 2x slower after repeating the test in loop for ~70 times (jumps from 0.22s to 0.49s and continues there).

Comment: @soulcheck Right, that likely just shows memory fragmentation. All this test shows is that allocating a lot of small objects degrades system performance. This is not a new result.

Comment: @Marcin maybe you should've posted that as an answer instead of arguing it doesn't happen? OP wasn't claiming any new discoveries, was he/she? edit: I didn't see your last edit.

Comment: @soulcheck But "it" isn't happening - class creation is not especially slow, and it only becomes slow under completely contrived conditions. The premise of this question is simply false: its results cannot be replicated according to the method disclosed in the question.

Comment: @Marcin so you're still agruing that it's not slow (even if that's a relative term and it IS slower in this case)? and you're still arguing it doesn't get slower with time even though you gave a correct justification for why it is getting slower?

Comment: @soulcheck I'm arguing that it is not in fact slow, under any reasonable definition of the term, except when a ludicrously large number of classes already exist, and that it is not the case that class creation uniquely makes class creation slow. You are analyzing something which does not actually occur or exist.

Comment: @Marcin you just substituted one relative term (slow) with another (reasonable). I rest my case here.

Comment: @soulcheck You rest your case on what, exactly? Reasonable is not a relative term, and even if it were, this would not invalidate the point I am making. Once again: the alleged phenomenon simply does not exist.

Comment: I can't reproduce it as given on my 64-bit Ubuntu machine with Python 2.7. 10000 consistently takes 0.28 seconds (±2%). Sure, doing 20000 at a time takes three times as long as doing 10000, and so on (I haven't bothered waiting for 100000), but that doesn't match the original point. It does suggest it, though.

Comment: > Why the creation of class in Python is slow? It isn't. It's not at all slow. Show me a case where you're needing to create 10,000 classes in such a manner as this and I'll show you a system being implemented the wrong way.

Comment: Here's something else to chew on, I just tried OP:s test on my machine; `calc(9000)` returns 4.38 (first run) and averages on 4.53 consequtive runs. `T("Haha()", "class Haha(object): pass").timeit(5000000)` gives 10.89 on first run and averages on 11.0 consequtive runs. System Load is zero.

Comment: @bos That seems spurious. Does it take many minutes to start up a python programme with several classes? If not, it suggests that your test is not representative of actual programme execution.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ahahaha! Gotcha!

Was this perchance done on a Python version without [this patch](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/ef15a5a230c13d6c69c73141b1c4adf8a676fed9)? (HINT: **IT WAS**)

Check the line numbers if you want proof.

**Marcin was right**: when the results look screwy you've probably got a screwy benchmark. Run `gc.disable()` and the results reproduce themselves. It just shows that when you disable garbage collection you get garbage results!

---

To be more clear, the reason running the long benchmark broke things is that:

- `timeit` disables garbage collections, so overly large benchmarks take much (exponentially) longer
- `timeit` wasn't restoring garbage collection on exceptions
- You quit the long-running process with an asynchronous exception, turning off garbage collection

Comment: Great answer, good job identifying the root cause of the gotcha.

Answer (score 33):

This might give you the intuition:

```
>>> class Haha(object): pass
...
>>> sys.getsizeof(Haha)
904
>>> sys.getsizeof(Haha())
64
```

Class object is **much** more complex and expensive structure than an instance of that class.

Comment: Veedrac's answer should be accepted. (Can you change an accepted answer this late?)

Answer (score 10):

A quick dis of the following functions:

```
def a():
    class Haha(object):
         pass



def b():
    Haha()
```

gives:

```
2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Haha')
            3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (object)
            6 BUILD_TUPLE              1
            9 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object Haha at 0x7ff3e468bab0, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
            12 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
            15 CALL_FUNCTION            0
            18 BUILD_CLASS         
            19 STORE_FAST               0 (Haha)
            22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
            25 RETURN_VALUE
```

and

```
2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (Haha)
            3 CALL_FUNCTION            0
            6 POP_TOP             
            7 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
            10 RETURN_VALUE
```

accordingly.

By the looks of it, it simply does more stuff when creating a class. It has to initialize class, add it to dicts, and wherever else, while in case of `Haha()` is just calls a function.

As you noticed doing garbage collection when it gets's too slow speeds stuff up again, so Marcin's right in saying that it's probably memory fragmentation issue.

Comment: This does not account for the behaviour OP is seeing, because these operations are simply not that expensive, and do not take that long anywhere else.

Comment: @Marcin The first operation DOES take more time, even if both are cheap. You can argue about methodology all you want but you won't change the fact that the first one simply has to be slower due to the fact that it does some extra operations instead of simply doing `CALL_FUNCTION`. Things can be different (ie when `__init__` is not empty and does something), but that's not the case here.

Comment: I'm not denying that class creation takes more time. I'm denying that the behaviour OP claims to have observed is real. Class creation is simply not that expensive.

Answer (score 3):

**It isn't**: Only your contrived tests show slow class creation. In fact, as @Veedrac shows in his answer, this result is an artifact of timeit disabling garbage collection.

**Downvoters:** Show me a non-contrived example where class creation is slow.

In any case, your timings are affected by the load on your system at the time. They are really only useful for comparisons performed at pretty much the same time. I get about 0.5s for 9000 class creations. In fact, it's about 0.3s on ideone, even when performed repeatedly: http://ideone.com/Du859. There isn't even an upward trend.

So, in summary, it is much slower on your computer than others, and there is no upwards trend on other computers for repeated tests (as per your original claim). Testing massive numbers of instantiations does show slowing down, presumably because the process consumes a lot of memory. You have shown that allocating a huge amount of memory slows a process down. Well done.

That ideone code in full:

```
from timeit import Timer as T
def calc(n):
return T("class Haha(object): pass").timeit(n)

for i in xrange(30):
print calc(9000)
```

Comment: 1) curiosity... sometimes i need create classes dynamically, so i did some experiment, and found this. 2) If I start a fresh python process and do the timing, i get 0.37sec, but it will become slower if you continue do the same thing.

Comment: @Proton How many times did you do it to go from 0.3s to 16s? I daresay that amount is not representative of any real usage.

Comment: Yeah, not representative. I got these numbers after 100k class creation(or more).

Comment: @Proton Well done, you have proven that if you contrive a test, you can create the appearance of an issue where there is none.

Comment: Do you mean you can't reproduce the result above?

Comment: @Proton Correct. My linked tests do not show that class creation is especially slow, and it does not show any upwards trend. I have not attempted to replicate your hundred-thousand test runs, for obvious reasons. In addition, no-one else has attempted to replicate your test and posted results, leaving the conclusion that they are spurious or relate to a purely contrived scenario.

Comment: Try this: start a fresh python process, the initial several "calc(10000)"s give a number of 0.5 on my machine. And try some bigger values, calc(100000), it can't end in even 10secs, interrupt it, and calc(10000), gives a 15sec.

Comment: @Proton OK, so there is a trend. This is still a completely contrived test.

Comment: +1; quite apart from whether there's a trend or not (I can't observe it on my machine for repeating, though for selecting a larger number I can), it's contrived and implementing a system which would do such things would be the Wrong Way. Now I'll see how my similar answer fares...

Comment: Thank you for keeping this answer up. You may have gotten complaints but you encouraged me to take a look. Turns out you were right about the test being wrong, but you assumed the answer was less fun than it really is.