# Why there's the difference between creating class in python 2.7 and python 3.4 performance

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
from timeit import Timer as T

def calc(n):
    return T("class CLS(object): pass").timeit(n)

print(calc(90000))
print(calc(90000))
print(calc(90000))

# python3.4
1.1714721370008192
1.0723806529986177
1.111804607000522

# python2.7
15.7533519268
16.7191421986
16.8397979736
```

Why is there so much difference in class creation time using different versions of python?
Tested on the same machine:

- i5-3450 CPU @ 3.10GHz
- 8gb ram

Comment: Of related interest: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10072428/3001761

Comment: I imagine object has something to do with it

Comment: I've narrowed the problem down to `timeit` calling `gc.disable()`. Since classes always create lots of cycles, disabling the collector means each `CLS` instance can't be deallocated. You can get a list of the tracked objects by calling `gc.get_objects()`. The performance is similar if you don't disable GC but just append each `CLS` instance to a list to keep it referenced. The puzzle it seems is why `_PyObject_GC_Malloc` is performing much worse in this case for Python 2.

Comment: Using your code snippet, I got 10.4693160057 in Python 2.7.3 and 10.087862968444824 in Python 3.2.3. By removing "object" I got 0.0276899337769 in Python 2.7.3. So it's unlikely that "object" has anything to do with it. There must have been a performance improvement between Python 3.2 and Python 3.4 that made the difference. It also seems that there are lots of small differences in class creation time between versions of Python, so it might not be possible to narrow this down to a single change.

Comment: You might want to look at the dis module to see what the differences are in the operation.

Answer (score 2):

`timeit` disables the garbage collector, which would otherwise break the cycles that keep a class object alive. Thus none of the classes gets deallocated until after `timeit` has finished.

`object.__subclasses__()` references these classes via an internal collection of weak references. The old list-based implementation of `tp_subclasses` searches the entire list each time to find a dead reference that can be replaced. This process takes more time with each additional subclass. On the other hand, the new dict-based design in 3.4 can add a reference in constant time. See [issue 17936](http://bugs.python.org/issue17936).

---

*Thanks to [@MichaelYounkin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26713356/why-theres-the-difference-between-creating-class-in-python-2-7-and-python-3-4-p#comment42165958_26713356) for pointing out how this is also slow in 3.2. Initially I tried to narrow the performance difference to a change in the small-object allocator between 2.x and 3.x, but after reading his comment I discovered that even 3.3 was considerably slower than 3.4. So I scanned over the [typeobject.c filelog](https://hg.python.org/cpython/log/04f714765c13/Objects/typeobject.c) to review recent changes.*

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem seems to be with old-style vs. new-style classes in python 2.7.

In python 3.4 you can see that the difference between using object and not using it is just the loading of the symbol (not that significant):

```
C:\TEMP>C:\Python34\python.exe
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:15:05) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> def a():
...   class A(object): pass
...
>>> def b():
...   class B(): pass
...
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(a)
  2           0 LOAD_BUILD_CLASS
              1 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object A at 0x020B8F20, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
              4 LOAD_CONST               2 ('A')
              7 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             10 LOAD_CONST               2 ('A')
             13 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (object)   # Extra step, not that expensive.
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            3 (3 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             19 STORE_FAST               0 (A)
             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             25 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(b)
  2           0 LOAD_BUILD_CLASS
              1 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object B at 0x020B8D40, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
              4 LOAD_CONST               2 ('B')
              7 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             10 LOAD_CONST               2 ('B')
             13 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (B)
             19 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

While on Python 2.7 you have another step that involves LOAD_TUPLE:

```
C:\Users\jsargiot\Downloads\so>C:\Python27\python.exe
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> def a():
...   class A(object): pass
...
>>> def b():
...   class B(): pass
...
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(a)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('A')
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (object)   # First extra step (just like 3.4)
              6 BUILD_TUPLE              1            # Second extra step, expensive
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object A at 01EAEA88, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
             12 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             18 BUILD_CLASS
             19 STORE_FAST               0 (A)
             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             25 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(b)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('B')
              3 LOAD_CONST               3 (())
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object B at 01EB8EC0, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
              9 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             15 BUILD_CLASS
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (B)
             19 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```